# Setting ssh to terminate remote process upon disconnection

Tags: ssh, process, remote, kill

I have been running some interactive shell scripts on a remote server.

Sometimes the ssh connection is lost, and I want the process on the other machine to die in such condition.

Can I configure the ssh connection to terminate remote process upon disconnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ClientAliveInterval` sshd configuration option to a non-zero value. Once the client fails to respond, the connection will be cut and the remote process will be sent a SIGHUP, stopping it (usually).

Comment: I cannot change the ssh configuration on the other part, just my parameters.

Comment: Well there's certainly nothing the *client* can do about it, seeing as how it's already disconnected...

Comment: Isn't there any request that can be made by the client upon **connection**, asking for process termination upon disconnection?